# hiding the async await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Does anyone know how to hide the async `await` inside a function?

---

Editing, since it seems that I was unclear.

What I want to do is to wrap the await inside a function, so the main outer function will not look like async code: 
**asyncFunction**: an async function.
**hideAsync**: a wrapper function that will remove the need to add the "await" keyword from the main code.
**run**: the main code that will look like a linear function.

Hoping this time I made myself clear :-/

```js
var someSome = {};

someSome.wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); 

someSome.asyncFunction = async (el) => {
    await someSome.wait(1000);
    alert("step 1");
}

someSome.hideAsync = async function(){
    await someSome.asyncFunction();
    alert("step 2");
}

someSome.run = async function(){
    someSome.hideAsync();
    alert("step 3");
}
someSome.run();
```

Comment: What do you mean hide?..  what expected result was you after.  You have missed the `await` on `someSome.hideAsync();` is that deliberate?.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to know if it's possible to do an async operation in a function call without using the `await` keyword in front of it *and still wait until that call is completed before moving on to the next line*.

**The answer is no, asynchronous operations need to be handled explicitly**, either through `await` or other means like `.then()`. You can definitely call async functions without `await` or `.then()`, but the execution will *not* wait for the operation to complete, it will continue to the next lines immediately.

Understanding asynchronous operations is vitally important in JavaScript, as they come up all the time. They can't be ignored and treated like synchronous functions. Using `await` is as close as you can get, and is *much* cleaner than it used to be with callback hell or `.then()`.